# Scrapy - basic scraper example returns no output

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running scrapy on Anaconda and have tried to run example code from [this DigitalOcean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3) as shown below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = "brickset_spider"
      start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']
```

I am a beginner with Scrapy so keep this in mind.This code executes but no output is shown. There is supposed to be output based on the article I got the code from. Please let me know how to view the information the spider gathers. I am running the module off my IDLE, if I try to do "runspider" in cmd it says it cannot find my python file even though I can see the file directory and open it on IDLE.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spider is missing a callback method to handle the response from http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016.

Try defining a callback method like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider


class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('I visited: {}'.format(response.url))
```

By default, Scrapy calls the `parse` method defined in your spider to handle the responses for the requests that your spider generates.

Have a look at the official Scrapy tutorial too: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html